# Toggling Rules in a Spotfire visualization

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am looking for a way to toggle rules on a visualization so that I can see either the top or bottom values of the Gross Margin % variable(but not both at the same time). Currently, the visualization is a cross table. The problem is that in the rules selection box you cant specify an expression for the rule type. I was going to create a drop down with vaules of Top and Bottom but this does not seem to be an option. Something to the tune of ${TopBottom} that is a drop down box with values of Top and Bottom. For the Value criteria I am using a text box where a number can be entered (${Number}):

[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps a conditional doc property? Really I think you'll need a calculated column for this too. Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is a number, you can make a property that is either 1 or negative 1 and multiply GM% by that property in the Rule.